# How to find the equations of the subspaces S= <[1, 2, -1]> and T = <[1,2,1], [-2,1,-3]> of $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find the equations that determine the vectors of the following subspaces S= <[1, 2, -1]> and T = <[1,2,1], [-2,1,-3]> of $R^3$?

I wrote S as z*[1,2,-1] and T as a*[1,2,1] + b*[-2,1,-3], but now I'm  not sure how to proceed. Is this alright?

Or should I write them as an equation of $[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ $\in$ $R^3$? so that the equation of S would be $x_1 + 2x_2 -x_3=0$?

Comment: Note that $S$ is a line and $T$ is a plane

Comment: Do you want a parametric form or a symmetric form of equations?

Comment: Parametric form

Comment: What you wrote is essentially parametric form (parameter $z$ for $S$ and parameters $a$ and $b$ for $T$)

Comment: The first part or the second one? I mean, the one with z, a and b or  the one with x1, x2, x3?

Comment: $(1)$ The first subspace is clearly defined by $V = [x, y, z] = \lambda [1,2, -1]$, that is, the line $x = \lambda, y = 2 \lambda, z = - \lambda$ 

$(2)$ Regarding the second subspace, check first if the vectors $[1,2,1]$ and $[-2,1, -3]$ are linearly independent in which case you have an equation of a plane $v = [x, y, z] = λ [1,2,1] + µ [-2.1, -3]$.